# In ASP.NET MVC, where the file is created by default, if I just specify the file name, and no path?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In ASP.NET MVC, where the file is getting created by default, if I just specify the file name, and no path?

I'm creating the file as :

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("MYSTERIOUS_log.txt", DateTime.Now.Precise() + msgString, Encoding.Unicode);
```

I looked inside the ASP.NET temporary folders, and also in the bin folder of application path of the current mvc web application. It might sound funny, but I even scanned my entire computer(all drives), for the specified file name, but still could not find it.

PS:

1. I can assure you, that there are no exceptions and the file is getting created properly.
2. I'm running my application in VS2010, on the MVC 3 framework, on a XP machine.
3. The application has also been hosted in IIS(ver 5.1).

So, where is my file gone?

Comment: Are you sure the file was actually written and that you did not get an exception (such as an access violation)?

Comment: @Oded : Yes. I'm sure because after that line of code, I tried recreating another file with a full path, and it gets created normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file will be saved in current directory, you can check which one it is by calling:

```
string currentDirectoryPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

In ASP.NET this is usually `C:\WINDOWS\system32` - but unless you have changed something in security settings you shouldn't have access there and this should end up with exception.

Comment: Thanks, sir. It really where it was. But what determines the current directory??? Mine was, "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0" ??? I just cannot relate from where it got set to this absurd value???

Comment: @MrClan - You are probably running your code using the MS dev server... That's the process that is running your code and this is the directory it lives in.